# Detecting an Apostrophe in a NSString?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, substring, apostrophe

I'm using Gamekit to send data via bluetooth between two devices. I want to get the name of the device that sent it, but if the name is "Bob's iPhone" I want to cut off the "'s iPhone". I first check for ending in "iPhone" or "iPod Touch".

```
 if ([name hasSuffix:@" iPhone"]) 
 {
  name = [name substringToIndex:[name length]-7];
 }
 else if ([name hasSuffix:@" iPod Touch"])
 {
  name = [name substringToIndex:[name length]-11];
 }
```

But when I do the same for "'s" it never returns true. Also the apostrophe looks slightly different then the default apostrophe.

```
if ([name hasSuffix:@"'s"]) 
{
  name = [name substringToIndex:[name length]-2];
}
```

Is there some trick to detecting apostrophes? Is there a way I can do this?

EDIT:
The apostrophe on the left is what name contains, but is not registering with hasSuffix:@"'s". The apostrophe on the right is the apostrophe I added.

[image]

Comment: I suppose you should do the same using the escape sequence for the ' I'm not exactly sure but try using escape sequence like \' for capturing the same please confirm me back if this solves your issue.

Comment: I did consider the escape sequence, but no luck. (I tried [name hasSuffix:@"\'s"])

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case of encoded string. You should make sure the string about this cases

is it `'s` or is it `´s` or is it `‘s` or some other character.

You may have some other character that is causing you problems.

These are my guess. Hoping this helps you to find out your problem.

Comment: How do I check for the different types of apostrophes?

Answer (score 0):

You want the [`rangeOfString:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:) method in `NSString`.

```
if ([name rangeOfString:@"'"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried using rangeOfString, but it still skips over the apostrophe. I think it's an encoded string issue.